# Create a custom taxonomy for WooCommerce without a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to create custom taxonomy for WooCommerce.
The default taxonomy is category and tag, however, I want more, for example, brands, materials and more.
For instance, I want Nike, Adidas... to be under brands; leather, canvas... to be under materials.
When I search online, most tutorials are using plugins, like Advanced Custom Fields, to create custom taxonomy for WooCommerce. However, I really don't want to use plugin for just one purpose.
I found this online: https://www.wppagebuilders.com/create-custom-taxonomy-without-plugin/  however it is for creating taxonomy for custom post type.
I instead want to create custom taxonomy for WooCommerce. Therefore, the code doesn't work for me.

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_taxonomy');
function register_custom_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x('Collections', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name'     => _x('Collection','taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items'      => __('Search Collection'),
        'all_items'         => __('All Collection'),
        'parent_item'       => __('Parent Collection'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Collection:'),
        'edit_item'         => __('Edit Collection'),
        'update_item'       => __('Update Collection'),
        'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Collection'),
        'new_item_name'     => __('New Collection Name'),
        'menu_name'         => __('Collections'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // make it hierarchical (like categories)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rewrite'    => array('slug' => 'Collection'),
    );
    register_taxonomy('Collections', 'wpp_shoe', $args); // Register the Taxonomy
}
```

Anybody has solution?

Answer (score 2):

To make your custom taxonomy linked to WooCommerce products, Some small adjustments are needed in your code *(mainly to define "product" post type as the 2nd argument in register_taxonomy() function)*:

```php
add_action('init', 'register_woocommerce_custom_taxonomy');
function register_woocommerce_custom_taxonomy() {
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce';

     // Register this custom taxonomy for "product" post type
    register_taxonomy('collection', array('product'), array(
        'labels'            => array(
            'name'              => _x('Collections', 'taxonomy general name', $text_domain),
            'singular_name'     => _x('Collection', 'taxonomy singular name', $text_domain),
            'search_items'      => __('Search Collection', $text_domain),
            'all_items'         => __('All Collection', $text_domain),
            'parent_item'       => __('Parent Collection', $text_domain),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Collection:', $text_domain),
            'edit_item'         => __('Edit Collection', $text_domain),
            'update_item'       => __('Update Collection', $text_domain),
            'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Collection', $text_domain),
            'new_item_name'     => __('New Collection Name', $text_domain),
            'menu_name'         => __('Collections', $text_domain),
        ),
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Like categories
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'collection'),
    ) ); 
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]